# Filepond - onprocessfiles callback are not triggered when there are preloaded images

Tags: reactjs, filepond

According to the Filepond docs, the "onprocessfiles" callback should trigger when all files in the list have been processed and this works fine when I don't have any preloaded files but does not work when I have it.

I using react-hook-form to handle the filepond state, and here is where I'm setting de preloaded files:

```
useEffect(() => {
 reset({
   ...response,
   sku: response.sku,
   imagenes: response.imagenes[0].imagen // filepond files array
   ? response.imagenes.map(img => ({
     source: `${response.proveedorId}/${img.imagen}`,
     options: {
       type: 'local',
       metadata: {
         id: img.imagenId,
         poster: `${server}/${response.proveedorId}/${img.imagen}`,
       },
     },
    }))
    : [], // if doesn't come any value assigns an empty array
   })
}, [...dependencies])
```

Here is my Filepont component:

```
      <FilePond
        files={filesArray}
        allowMultiple={true}
        allowReorder={true}
        allowProcess={true}
        maxFiles={maxFiles}
        labelIdle={`Arrastra aquí tus imágenes,
      <span class="filepond--label-action">Elegir imágenes...</span>.`}
        className="FilePondCustom"
        onaddfilestart={() => console.log('addFileStart')}
        onprocessfiles={() => console.log('all files has been processed')}
        server={{
          url: `${server}/upload/`,
          load: (source, load, error) => {
            if (source) {
              fetch(source, {
                mode: 'no-cors',
              })
                .then(res => {
                  return res.blob()
                })
                .then(blob => {
                  return load(blob)
                })
                .catch(error)
            }
          },
        }}
        maxParallelUploads={maxFiles}
        onupdatefiles={fileItems => setValue(name, fileItems)}
      />
```

The expected result is that the "onprocessfiles" callback would trigger even when I have preloaded files.

**Filepond: *4.28.2***

**react-filepond: *7.1.1***

**react: *17.0.1***

**react-hook-form: *7.1.0***

[FilepondDocs/properties/callbacks](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/instance/properties/#callbacks)

Comment: 'local' files aren't "processed" they're a reflection of the server state. Files in 'limbo' state should trigger the `onprocessfiles` event. In this situation I think it's best to listen for `onprocessfile` and then test if the state is as you need to to be manually.